# Sort object in JavaScript with UnderScorejs

Tags: javascript, sorting, underscore.js

I have an object like this :

```
{tsg2b: 1, fjdlf: 0}
```

Now i need to sort this object based on the value for example i need the result something like this :

```
{fjdlf: 0,tsg2b: 1}
```

Comment: You can not sort object directly.

Comment: Convert each to an object of it self and then sort an Array.

Comment: @limelights can you explain a little more. any way to sort this object?

Comment: @MBehtemam You need to put them in an array and sort the array (`[{tsg2b: 1}, {fjdlf: 0}]`). You can't keep the same data structure since objects are unordered by specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take the object into an array and then sort the array because object cannot be sorted in java script. try the following --

```
var test = {tsg2b: 1, fjdlf: 0} 
var sortable = [];
for (var item in test)
      sortable.push([item, test[item]])
sortable.sort(function(a, b) {return a[1] - b[1]})
```